# Wygwam Grid Compatibility

Tags: wygwam, grid

The *Wygwam* [changelog](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/changelog.html) states that v3.3 "Added Grid compatibility." But when I create a *Grid* field, *Wygwam* is not offered as an available field type.

EE 2.8.1
Wygwam 3.3.1

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: Have you installed Wygwam as a field type?

Comment: Yes. I can create a Wygwam field in a field group. I just can't add a Wygwam field to a Grid field.

Comment: Have you visited the wygwam settings page or run module updates? By doing those things it can sometimes fix inconsistencies like these

Answer (score 0):

If it's an update, try to clean the cache of your browser and of EE.

Comment: It was not an update. I have cleared all caches (EE and browser) and it still isn't offered as a field type in Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to click the Run Module Update under Addons -> modules. Also visit the wygwam settings page. Doing these things should update the field type list in grid.